# Document Name (conversion php to ?)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

Hi
I am currently using php to add the document name so example.

```
folder/<?phpecho basename(__FILE__, '.' . pathinfo(__FILE__,
PATHINFO_EXTENSION));?>_button.png
```

What i have noticed is that by using php to do this and having multiple examples of this it is dramatically increasing my page load time. What i wish is for a similar method using client side scripting.

Comment: Did you already try declare a constant with this value once a time and use it?

Comment: I highly, highly doubt that this is "dramatically increasing my page load time" for you -- there is very little work being done by this code.  What tool have you used to determine that this is indeed increasing your page loading time?

Comment: @Felipe Sorry i don't fully understand. @Charles I could easily tell by watching it load, i don't mean dramatically i mean 1-10 seconds depending on connection speed. Finally i do not have on instance of this i have this code used 7 times on each page.

Answer (score 0):

If you are truly convinced that this is slowing your page times down, then you need to prove it.  Use the [microtime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php) function to test each function call and see what's actually slowing things down.  For example:

```
<?php
    $t0 = microtime(TRUE);
    $ext = pathinfo(__FILE__, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $t1 = microtime(TRUE);
    $filename = basename(__FILE__, '.' . $ext);
    $t2 = microtime(TRUE);

    echo "pathinfo() took " . $t1-$t0 . " seconds.  ";
    echo "basename() took " . $t2-$t1 . " seconds.  ";
    echo "total time: " . $t2-$t0 " . " seconds.";
?>
```

And if you determine that it is taking too long, find a better way to do it. Or, at least save this calculated value to a variable and echo that throughout the multiple places you need it.